# Fazer uma função que recebe uma string com numeros e retornar o maior e o menor valor

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sua função receberá uma string como parâmetro. Separe essa string utilizando o caracter de ' ' e retorne uma string contendo o maior número e o menor número (necessariamente nesta ordem).

```
function  maiorEMenor(numbers) {

    var numeros = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i +=2) {
        numeros.push(parseInt(numbers.substr(i, i+1)))
      }
  
      var maior = Math.max.apply(null, numeros)
      var menor = Math.min.apply(null, numeros)
      
      return maior.toString() + ' ' + menor.toString()
 
}
```

O codigo funciona exceto se o parametro começar com numeros negativos ou for somente um numero.

Exemplo: se a entrada for '1 2 3 4 5' ele retorna '5 1';
mas se a entrada for '42' ele retorna '4 2' em vez de '42 42'
e com entradas negativas ele fica retorna NaN

Comment: Substr está selecionado 1 character por vez, tenta com String split

Comment: A menos que seja obrigatório usar `Math.min` e `Math.max`, não vejo necessidade. Pois vc está criando um array, e depois cada chamada (tanto `min` quanto `max`) percorrem todo o array, ou seja, são dois loops sendo feitos. Sendo que nem precisa de array, dá pra fazer tudo de uma vez: https://ideone.com/NhoCD2

Answer (score 1):

Reduzindo seu código atual, tudo fica mais fácil usando *split*.

```
function maiorEMenor(numbers) {

    const e_num = numbers.split(" ");

    let maior = Math.max.apply(null, e_num)
    let menor = Math.min.apply(null, e_num)
  
    return maior.toString() + ' <= maior : menor => ' + menor.toString()
 
}
console.log(maiorEMenor("4 5 6"));
```

[image: Resultado]

Espero que seja isso que procura.

Comment: No exercicio é para ser somente um parametro, tipo "4 5 6" e eu não consegui usar o split pra fazer isso

Comment: seja mais claro!, pois no exemplo já há um único parâmetro passando os valores 4,5,6. Ex: `maiorEMenor("4 5 6");`